# What it the distribution for square root of sum of squares of two independent normal distributed random variable?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, chi-distribution

What it the distribution for square root of sum of squares of two independent normal distributed random variable? Assuming they have zero mean and same non-zero variance. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ ~ $N(0,\sigma^2)$, what is the distribution for $Z = \sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$? Looking for any feedbacks or comments.

Comment: Hint: $X^2+Y^$ is an exponential random variable.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi_distribution.

Comment: This reads like a textbook-style exercise (it's certainly simple enough to be one). In any case "looking for any feedback" is a bit too general (you didn't do anything to give feedback on). Can you be more explicit about the source of the problem?

Comment: This is related to the Raleigh distribution.  That is $Z/\sigma$  has Raleigh distribution. I assume that you are taking the positive square root as is conventional.

Comment: Is there also a "named" distribution, if the expectation values of X and Y are non zero?